# Godot Play Project/Scene window always on top issue

Tags: godot

I am running Godot 3.2 on my Mac. When I play a scene or project, I would like to keep the windows on top of Godot so I can make changes live. I have seen that it can be done: just right click on the window and select the option. However, in my case, this isn't happening: the menu option doesn't show up. I tried to select "windows run on top" in the project settings, but still while the play scene is running and I touch anywhere on the editor, the screen goes behind.

See the photo. I don't know what my version is.

[image]

Comment: This is not an option of the program but of your window manager. You will probably want to search for how to do the equivalent thing with the macOS WM, if that is even possible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, seems like it is a Godot feature, there is a "Windows on the top" option in Project settings, but isn't working in my case, maybe as you said I need that thing you suggest. I don't know it is is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys, I have found the solution so easy :(

To bring a similar pop up window in Mac and with Godot 3.2 I just need to hover over the resize option on the left top window.

You can send/move the Play scene pop up window as you will do with any other window.